# Less Filewatcher compiler in PHPStorm

Tags: less, phpstorm

what I'am doing wrong when trying to compile the `.less` files into `.css` with *PHPStorm File watcher* ?

Here is the screenshot, (pls open [THIS LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldryY.png) to see the full size of the image):
[image]

I installed `npm install -g less`, after getting installed `NodeJS`. It works fine the compiler `lessc` when using `cmd.exe` - Command Line Tool in Windows OS with this command:

`lessc custom.less custom.css`, but it wont do anything inside PHPStorm in Filewatcher.

Any clue what I should correct, pls ?

Comment: Well ... you are doing it wrong. Why do you point to `node.exe` if from command line you executing `lessc` command? `node.exe` is just a nodejs interpreter. Why do you expect to see the same results if you trying to execute 2 different commands? **A:** You should point file watcher to `lessc.cmd` (provide full path -- it's in your `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder

Comment: @LazyOne - that was the default one provided by PHPStorm, actually i figured it out, by modifying **Argument** box with this code `C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less\bin\lessc $FileName$ -yui-compress`.

Comment: First time I see that it suggests `node.exe` -- it should not do it (unless you were trying it before for something else, e.g. nodejs support, and it somehow got into file watchers). In any case: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5481646#5481646 -- the correct path to `lessc` executable is `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd`

Comment: Yes that's what I saw first time, but it didn't work on PhpStorm 6.0.3. So I was like WTF, it shows an error that the only accepted filetypes are `win32` for executables, and not shell-ones like `.bat,.cmd,` etc...  I'am confused why it's not working like it's recommended, but as far what i've done there it works flawlessly

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For those who want to configure LESS auto compiler inside their IDE PHPStorm, you can do it in that way:

1. Download and install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
2. Open Terminal/Shell/Command line, `cmd.exe` for Windows Environment
3. Inside **Command line** terminal, type `npm install -g less` and wait for LESS to be downloaded and installed.
4. In PHPStorm open Settings window: *File > Settings (CTRL+ALT+S)*
5. Navigate to *File Watchers* (or search for it inside SETTINGS Window)
6. Click on **+** on the right side of the Settings dialog to create a new File Watcher and configure it as shown on picture:
   [image]
   And this is how your folder structure should look like for the settings on the previous picture:
   [image]
7. Save it and test it, each time you type something inside the `.less` file, it will be automatically compiled into `.css` you've defined before in File Watcher's setting dialog.
   To untouch the source less files, create a `template.less` like shown in picture and subload the source files there before doing styling anything.

```
/*!
 * Your commented code which wouldn't be removed in compiled .css because of "!" mark
 */
 /*
  * This comment will be removed in compiled .css file because of no "!" after "/*"
  */

// Core source files of Twitter's Bootstrap
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/responsive";

// Core source file of Font Awesome Icons
@import "font-awesome/font-awesome";

// Connected plugins
@import "plugins/datepicker";
@import "plugins/redactor";

/*!
 * General template styles below
 */

/* -------------------------------------------------------------- */
/**** PRECONFIG, OVERRIDES, VARIABLES, TYPOGRAPHY ****/
/* -------------------------------------------------------------- */
// VARIABLES.LESS Override
//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Colors
@whiteSmoke:            #f5f5f5;

// Typo
@sansFontFamily:        "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
@serifFontFamily:       Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
@monoFontFamily:        Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
```

Comment: i guess there is a plugin already available inside the PHPStorm, so I suggest you to go try that plugin, if it won't help, this will surely do

Comment: I know there is, but I'd prefer doing things the inbuilt way. Oh well, I did get it running thanks to you, thanks.

Comment: I can't express my gratitude to you enough for posting this solution as this seems to be the only working solution and I was very frustrated trying to find the right one. Thanks a TON for sharing!!!