# ParseError: Unrecognised input in lessc on line 1, column 1: #!/usr/bin/env node

Tags: less, phpstorm

I opened my PhpStorm and suddenly it won't compile my LESS files, even though I manually wrote `lessc path/to/file.less path/to/file.css`.

It makes an error that I can't understand nor find any information on.

The error I receive is as shown on the picture. The file with the error in it are the opened file as well.

[image: Image with error]

I made some major changes in file watchers as I use, but it worked right after and after restarting it won't. My settings there are like shown here:

[image: Image with settings]

What did I do wrong here?

EDIT: My setup came from following [this guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508252/less-filewatcher-compiler-in-phpstorm).

*******SOLUTION********

I changed argument with `--no-color $FileName$`

Comment: Don’t specify both `lessc.bat` and the path to `lessc`. You just need the former.

Comment: Why did you set path to lessc as argument to itself (lessc.cmd)? That's wrong. How does it work from plain command line?

Comment: `Arguments` file from File Watcher settings should not contain the path to lessc -- it's already in `Program` field.

Comment: What should i leave in Arguments? When i leave it empty i get error as well

"cmd.exe /D /C call C:/Users/jannl/AppData/Roaming/npm/lessc.cmd
lessc: no input files"

And then a list of commands